# In SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) does individual services run as separate server?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soa

Big banks follow Service Oriented Architecture for their functioning.
They may have more that 50 services so do they run individual services as separate server or they group services ?

Can anyone explain this in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

According to SOA, each service should be able to serve the service independently and hence could be hosted on a separate server.
But all this servers should communicate  between each other internally,so the system as a whole is aware of the services offered by each server and the outside world can hit a single endpoint while requesting a service. Internally a routing module will identify the server which offers the particular service and serve it.

It could be also possible that there could be more than one server serving the same request if the load expected is  high.

Also the term server could mean a runtime, something like a JVM if the service is Java based or it could be a machine too.

according to wiki:

> Every computer can run any number of services, and each service is
>   built in a way that ensures that the service can exchange information
>   with any other service in the network without human interaction and
>   without the need to make changes to the underlying program itself.

Normally similar nature services or services communicating with same code base or DB server or another application server etc are grouped together. While a high volume service or long running service could be served separately to speed up the system.

Comment: I think if we host the services individually then it is the concept of microservices

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) is to have flexibility for each module( exposed as service) to have it's freedom of deployment, implementation an expansion with least affecting other modules. So all these services either they could be hosted on single server with different ports or they could be on different server.

Usually at big banks, there would be a team owning each service.Each service is deployed on different server. In fact each service may be deployed on many servers for Scalability and fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the services are hosted by an Enterprise Service Bus, a component which publishes the services to all information systems of the organization and also to the external B2B customers (via B2B gateway).

The services hosted on ESB may utilize services provided by backend systems. These services of backend system are considered as private and are only consumed via ESB. This approach eliminates the spaghetti mess which comes if everybody integrates with anybody.

Most of ESB systems I have come accross were high available solutions with a HA database, a cluster of application servers and a load balancer, all together creating a platform to ensure stability and performance of the services.

The number of services in an enterprise can be very large, I have been involved in projects with hundreds of services, largest corporations can run thousands of services.

I recommend to [check wikipedia for more about ESB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus).